# A subsystem within web application for periodic tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, windows-services

To be precise: I have a .NET web forms system. I need a way to check some values and perform tasks, depending on these values in periodic manner. Let's say: Every month I have to check if my customers credit cards are still valid. There some other tasks/checking in short periods.

What is the best approach to the subject. I thought about Windows Service but I read about WCF. Please advise what is the modern and good way to solve this task. I'm thinking about .NET 4.0.

Comment: Important point, will your periodic task require any interface with the user or can it be completely autonomous ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with ".NET" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: A simple approach is just to check for periodic tasks on a slow timer and at application startup.

Answer (score 4):

WCF is just an interface that can run in either Windows Service or IIS. You use this WCF interface to trigger some synchronous or asynchronous actions.

Your case sounds like you want a Windows Service on timer to perform validation on data stored in a data base or file.

If you want to start a process on demand then adding a WCF endpoint might be useful, if the timer approach is good enough, then you need not bother with WCF.

References for hosting WCF in Windows Process

- [microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)
- [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38160/WCF-Service-Library-with-Windows-Service-Hosting)

Answer (score 3):

As you've surmised, a Windows Service is a good approach to this problem.

Similarly, you could write a Console application and have it run via a scheduled task in Windows.

It depends on how your backend works and what you're most familiar with really.

Writing a console application is very simple to do, but it's not perhaps the best approach as you need to ensure that a user is logged on so that the scheduled task can run.

A service is slightly more complicated to implement, but it has the benefits of being integrated into the OS properly.

MSDN has a good guide to writing a service in C#, and you don't necessarily need WCF:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like quartz.net. See link - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: a possible issue is that the version that presently supports .net 4 is in development.

Answer (score 1):

If you have limited control over server (i.e. only regular HTTP pages allowed):

You can also use a web page to trigger the task - this way you don't need any additional components installed on server. Than have some other machine configure periodic requests to the page(s) that trigger tasks. Make sure that tasks are restartable and short enough - so you can finish each on regular page request. Page can respond with "next task to run" data so your client page can continue pinging server till whole operation is finished.

Note: Trying to run long running tasks inside web service process is unreliable due to app pool/app domain recycles.

Comment: Also, if you *need* your task to run every 2 weeks, this approach won't ensure that someones around to access the website when you need it; but as Alexei said; if you've got no server access then this is one way of achieving the goal. Not recommended in any other circumstance though!